# How to get API for TargetingIdeaSelector (Google API to get keyword search data) in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js

This API is available in other languages, but I want the code in Node.JS.

Answer (score 3):

From this source : https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/targeting-idea-service#python_4

It looks like you have to send a POST request, the problem is the request is build from [targetingIdeaService.get function](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/TargetingIdeaService#get):

```
targetingIdeaService.get(selector)
```

The selector itself can be guessed from the docs :

```
offset = 0
PAGE_SIZE = 10
selector = {
    'ideaType': 'KEYWORD',
    'requestType': 'IDEAS',
    'requestedAttributeTypes':[
        'KEYWORD_TEXT',
        'SEARCH_VOLUME',
        'CATEGORY_PRODUCTS_AND_SERVICES'
     ],
     'paging':{
         'startIndex': str(offset),
         'numberResults': str(PAGE_SIZE)
     },
     'searchParameters':[{
         'xsi_type': 'RelatedToQuerySearchParameter',
         'queries': ['space cruise']
     }]
}
```

But you do not have access to the way the request is constructed from this object.

I would suggest you to use [this unofficial googleads node library](https://github.com/ErikEvenson/googleads-node-lib/) since it seems to handle `targetingIdeaService`. Or even [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-adwords) since it has more recent developments.